# How to get current userdata from firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to flutter and firestore. I´m building a social media app and need to get some userinformation from the current logged in user to the user profilepage. Surch as username, email etc. 
I have manage to get the userdata up to firestore, but Im struggling to get the current userinformation back to my project.

I've tryed this method, and it does get the userinformation back from firestore, but not the current userinformation unfortuinetly. 
I guess the plroblem is that Im stuck on the first document in my database on firestore?

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream:
      Firestore.instance.collection('userData').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 75.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              snapshot.data.documents[0]['userName'],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child:
                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['email']),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}),
```

I would really appreciate any potential solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - How to return current user from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244652/flutter-how-to-return-current-user-from-firestore)

Comment: The answer depends on how you store the user data in Firebase. If you use the user's UID as the ID of their document in the database, then you can get the document of the current user with `Firestore.instance.collection('userData').document(FirebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)`. I might be missing an `await` in there somewhere, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you Frank! This got me one step closer! But I'm still facing some issues. Would you please explaine how I should  use the user's UID as the ID of the their document in the database? As said, Im quite new to this whole firebase consept... so please bare with me. My code right now, store the userdata in Firebase as followed: _firestore.collection('userData').add({
          'userName': userName,
          'cityName': cityName,
          'instrument': instrument,
          'email': email });  I hope this make sanse, Thanks again for your respond!

Answer (score 5):

```
      Future<void> _getUserName() async {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .document((await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid)
            .get()
            .then((value) {
          setState(() {
            _userName = value.data['UserName'].toString();
          });
        });
      }
```

Add the _userName to the initstate like this

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserName();
  }
```

and call it like this

```
  child: Text('Hello $_userName,'),
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firebase authentication, then

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

will get you the current logged in user. After that, you can do

```dart
var email = user.email;
var userName = user.displayName;
```

to get relevant user info.

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense to me, but I´m still facing som issues. 1# I get an error on "await" in the func "FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();" 2#  I havn´t used the FirebaseAuth on the userName. Its just a requierment for the user in the registrationpage to navigate to the next page. So I have the userName and some outher requierd userinformation such as cityName, in a document on firestore. Do you have any sugestions in this matter? Thanks again for your respond!